# How to show a video file in winforms?

Tags: winforms, video, c++-cli

I want to play a video file in winforms, having a control that decides if to play or stop.
Is there an easy way to do that in winforms?
Is there a simple framework to help me do that?

Comment: If you're using WinForms, you're not using C++, you're using C++/CLI (totally different language).

Comment: I agree.  Do you know about controls for playing videos? maybe a simple library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click the toolbox, Choose Items.  Select the COM components tab and tick "Windows Media Player".  Drop it on your form.  Programming guide [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562388%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can embed Windows Media Player in your form using a COM component:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383953%28v=vs.90%29.aspx